# iphone version of ion-button focus background doesn't change + IONIC2

Tags: ios, iphone, html, css, ionic2

I am using this button and on android if i tap button the background converts from blue to black and color converts from yellow to white. 
But in iOS build when i tap it that background doesn't stay black. When my finger will leave screen that comes back to original state.

```
<button ion-button block round outline color="danger" (click) = "gotoNextWithParent()">
      Parent
    </button>


button:focus{ 
  background:#000;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN:

**Safari 7.0.5:**

- Clicking on a `<button>` **DOES NOT** give it the focus, even with a `tabindex`
- Clicking on an `<a>` give it the focus, **ONLY** when it has a `tabindex`

**iOS 7.1.2**

- Tapping on a `<button>` **DOES NOT** give it the focus, even with a `tabindex`
- Tapping on an `<a>` give it the focus, **ONLY** when it has a `tabindex`

So, according to the above, you have no luck on giving the focus on a `button` and you should instead, use an `anchor` and give that the focus.

```css
a {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: ButtonText;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button:focus, 
a:focus {
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button>A button</button>
</br>
</br>
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="1">An anchor</a>
```

[**JSBin to check on iOS**](http://jsbin.com/pefogej) (tested on iOS 10.3.3)

Information on MDN:

- [Clicking and focus on a button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus)
- [Clicking and focus on an anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Clicking_and_focus)

Comment: Still the same in iOS build

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer, please give it a try